# Rails 3 diffence between current_date and created_at value not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql-9.1, datediff

I'm doing some research about time functions in rails and I'm trying to get the difference between 2 dates and multiply the result by a number and finally check if the less than another value. The formula would be like this.

```
where("? - created_at * (amount * 1.2 / 30) < total", Time.now)
```

But this is what I got.

PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone * numeric

HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying a date doesn't make sense, and that's what you're doing:

```
regress=> SELECT (TIMESTAMP '2012-01-01 00:00:00') * 1.2;
ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone * numeric
LINE 1: SELECT (TIMESTAMP '2012-01-01 00:00:00') * 1.2;
                                                 ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I think you *intended* to multiply the *difference*, in which case you need parens because `*` binds tighter than `-` in operator precedence. So:

```
(? - created_at) * (amount * 1.2 / 30)
```

Comment: well, I changed my code just like you said and the error remains

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to cast the difference to a float first (using .to_f).

somehing like

`where("? - created_at.to_f * (amount * 1.2 / 30) < total", Time.now.to_f)`

Alternatively, since it is complaining about time zones, `to_timestamp()`  will return a a timestamp with time zone

**EDIT:**
***To add timezone*** to your app add something like this to the module code which is in `config/application.rb`

```
module YourApp
    class Application < Rails::Application
    config.time_zone = 'Cairo' #your timezone goes here
    config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
end
```

Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.

[Time Zones on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

If your app is on Heroku, the magic command becomes:

`heroku config:add TZ="America/Los_Angeles"`

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll try this. By the way, do you know how to set my time zone to Bogotá/Latin America?

Comment: sorry that didn't work for you. to set timezone you can edit your `application.rb` file. I will include this in my answer in order to preserve formatting

Answer (score 0):

Well, I used a postgres function called age, which receives two dates, it can be improved, though

```
(((prestamos.monto * 1.2) / 30) * (extract(day from age(now(),prestamos.created_at))))
```